# What is the syntax for detecting Mongoose events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to detect the open event based on Mongoose documentation [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose):

> Once connected, the open event is fired on the Connection instance. If
>   you're using mongoose.connect, the Connection is mongoose.connection.
>   Otherwise, mongoose.createConnection return value is a Connection.

I'm using mongoose.connect so I would imagine it is something like

```
mongoose.connection.on('open', () => {
  console.log('connected!');
})
```

But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a connection there are two events to listen on the opening of connection which happens only once we use:

```
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
});
```

the error event which can happen any time and more than one time:

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
```

check the docs [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this and detecting Mongoose events.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const URI = 'connection path';

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || URI, { useNewUrlParser: true });

// When successfully connected
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
    console.log('Established Mongoose Default Connection');
});

// When connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log('Mongoose Default Connection Error : ' + err);
});
```